# Locking a Row in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm modifying an application to implement row locking in codeigniter. I used MySQL to do a serialisable transaction lock, which worked as it should when I tried in MySQL workbench.

But when trying Codeigniter, it seems that nothing ever happens, other users can still modify data in the row. I've tried changing the order of transactions and queries around, but nothing seems to work. The database runs on Innodb.

I've tried several methods including the one below which apparently works. But there's no locking of rows and I can update concurrently between multiple windows.